# VueJS; wait for element before running local JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a few components, javascript, and elements that needs to be ran in a certain order.

1st - `opensheetmusicdisplay.min.js` which I have in my index.html file. This isn't an issue.

2nd - `<div id="xml">`

3rd - `xml-loader.js` which depends on both the "xml" div and `opensheetmusicdisplay.min,js`

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script rel="preload" src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/osmd/opensheetmusicdisplay.min.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="xml2">words go here</div>
    <div id="app"></div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript part I'm attempting to test:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("xx == ", document.getElementById("xml2"));
}

alert("xx2 == ", document.getElementById("xml2"));

alert(JSON.stringify(opensheetmusicdisplay, null, 1));
```

When I run this, they both instances of `"xml2"` show blanks. The `opensheetmusicdisplay` does show data, which means it is reading from the source in the `head` section in `index.html`

It was pointed out to me in the comments that alert only take one argument. That's a mistake that I'm going to let sit for the moment. The error in the console is TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Now, this is the main.js. There are a lot of comments because of my various ideas:

// vue imports and config
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

```
// page imports
import Notation from '@/components/Notation'
import HomePage from '@/components/HomePage'
// component imports and registration
import { FoundationCSS } from  '@/../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css'
Vue.component('foundation-css', FoundationCSS)

import SideNav from '@/components/SideNav'
Vue.component('side-nav', SideNav);

// import * as Osmd from '@/../public/js/osmd/opensheetmusicdisplay.min.js'
// Vue.component('osmd-js', Osmd)
// import { OsmdJs } from '@/components/Osmd'

import * as XmlJs from '@/../public/js/osmd/xml-loader.js'
Vue.component('xml-js', XmlJs)
// import XLoad from '@/components/XmlLoader'

const router =  new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/',
          components: {
              maininfo: HomePage
          }
        },
        { path: '/chromatic-scales/c-chromatic-scale',
          components: {
              maininfo: Notation// ,
              // xmlloader: XLoad
          }
        }
    ]
})


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
})
```

I registered `XmlJs` as global because this is the only way out of 100 things that actually works. I then embed it in `Notation.vue` like so:

```
<template>
<div>

  <div id="xml">
    {{ notation.data }}
  </div>
  <xml-js />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'


export default ({
data () {
return {
notation: null,
}
},
mounted () {
axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/chromatic-scales/c-chromatic-scale')
    .then(result => (this.notation = result))
}})


</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

The last file is the meat and potatoes of what I'm trying to do. The `xml-loader.js` slurps the data from `<div id="xml">` and does whatever magic the program does in order to render the output I want. The issue is that there doesn't seem to be anyway to wait for the stuff in `{{ notation.data }}`.

I am new to using vuejs and front-end javascript frameworks in general. I do recognize the code is probably not optimal at this time.

Comment: alert takes a single argument - so `alert("xx == ", document.getElementById("xml2"));` will only ever show `xx == ` ... have you considered using debugging tools that exist in your browser ... `console.log` for example

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, you are right. There is nothing coming back from the "xml" div though. That still shows as null. I have a website where this stuff works w/o VueJS, so I know this does work before trying out VueJS on this version. It just seems very difficult to get any local js files running and it's even harder to get things to see each other. Those are the main issues I'm dealing with here.

Comment: What does *coming back from the "xml" div* mean? What exactly do you try? Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. As long as you run the script below div, `document.getElementById("xml2")` will output the element and not null.

Comment: @EstusFlask -> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. That's the error in the console.

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. Codesandbox or something. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EstusFlask I'll try that out.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm sorry, there is no way to run this thing without all the files above. It seems that the embedded, jsfiddle, etc, only allow one file at a time. I'm really just trying to describe the issue I'm having as I understand it.

Comment: The question may not contain workable demo but it should contain all necessary information to understand what's going on on your end. I'm not sure I understand it correctly. *this is the JavaScript part* - where is it evaluated? There are `xml2` and `xml`, are both of them needed? Please, explain what you're trying to achieve in the end, currently the question seems to be XY problem. If you need to load data into `<div id="xml">`  and render it with osmd, this would be a problem statement.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, that's the general idea, XML is rendered in <div id="xml>, but when I attempt to call it in in xml-loader.js, there is no data in getElementById("xml"). The issue appears to be that the local javascrtipt file fires before the DOM is ready. It's just my guess. I was able to handle a similar issue with "opensheetmusic.min.js" via rel="preload"

Comment: What exactly is xml-loader? Is it developed by you? Should it really access it like getElementById("xml")? Yes, this is the issue. The solution is to access Vue-related DOM only inside Vue app.

Comment: @EstusFlask OSMD is an open source program that renders sheet music. I had to modify xml-loader to take in raw XML because it usually expects local MusicXML files. This here is the general idea that I'm working off of, so I know everything does work: http://muse-env.eba-gb2hjxvj.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/chromatic-scales/c-chromatic-scale (I'm reviving an older project, so bear with me). The sheet music won't render within Vue.

Comment: It seems that you're making a detour. You don't really need to output it as `{{ notation.data }}`. osmd doesn't render it back to div, does it? From what I see, it can render from a string. In the snippet I posted, it could be done like `const result = await axios
    .get(...); await openSheetMusicDisplay.load(result.data); openSheetMusicDisplay.render();`

Comment: @EstusFlask OSMD does render to a new div, which is predefined and generally static on the webpage. Thanks for your help in all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is race condition where DOM element is not available at the time when it's accessed. The solution is to not access DOM elements created by Vue outside of it. DOM element is ready for use only after asynchronous request:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div ref="xml" id="xml">
    {{ notation.data }}
  </div>
  <xml-js />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default ({
data () {
return {
notation: null,
}
},
async mounted () {
  const result = await axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/chromatic-scales/c-chromatic-scale')
  this.notation = result;
  this.$nextTick(); // wait for re-render
  renderXml(this.$ref.xml); // pass DOM element to third-party renderer
}})
```

Comment: I had to use `Vue.nextTick` instead of `this.nextTick`

Comment: It's `this.$nextTick`, not `nextTick`. It's available, as long as `this` is correct, https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

Answer (score 0):

You can import xml-loader.js into the Notation.vue as a function. Then you can simply do something like this:

```
mounted () {
  axios.get(PATH).then(result => {
    this.notation = result
    let xmlResult = loadXML(result)
    doSomethingWithResult(xmlResult)
  }
},
methods: {
  doSomethingWithResult (result) {
    // do something
  }
}
```